# Set MVC SelectList text to two fileds

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc

I have simple SelectList in my ActionResult:

```
ViewBag.ItemId = new SelectList(db.Items, "ItemId", "Name");
```

I'd like to show the item name with the item Specification

This is not working:

```
ViewBag.ItemId = new SelectList(db.Items, "ItemId", "Name" + "Specification");
```

Is there is an easy way to do this?

Comment: use `db.Items.Select(x => new SelectListItem{ Value = x.Id.ToString(), Text = x.Name + " " + x.Specification })`

Comment: Thanks! My question is duplicate, but I think the answer is differ. Thanks again